# GCC generates test for nonzeroness even if the zero value is guaranteed

Tags: c++, assembly, optimization, x86-64

Consider the following class, created mainly for benchmarking purposes:

```
class String {
  char* data_; 
public:
  String(const char* arg = "") : data_(new char[strlen(arg) + 1]) { strcpy(data_, arg); }
  String(const String& other) : String(other.data_) { }
  String(String&& other) noexcept : data_(other.data_) { other.data_ = nullptr; }
  String& operator=(String other) noexcept { swap(other); return *this; }  
  ~String() { delete[] data_; }
  void swap(String& rhs) noexcept { std::swap(data_, rhs.data_); }
  const char* data() const { return data_; }   
};
void swap(String& lhs, String& rhs) noexcept { lhs.swap(rhs); }
```

I am trying to compare the efficiency of swapping of two of its instances with custom `swap` and `std::swap`. For custom `swap`, GCC 8.2 (`-O2`) generates the following x86_64 assembly:

```
mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsi]
mov     QWORD PTR [rdi], rdx
mov     QWORD PTR [rsi], rax
ret
```

which exactly matches swapping of two pointers. However, for `std::swap`, the generated assembly is:

```
  mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsi]
  mov     QWORD PTR [rsi], 0    // (A)
  mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
  mov     QWORD PTR [rdi], 0    // (1)
  mov     QWORD PTR [rsi], rax  // (B)
  mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]  // (2)
  mov     QWORD PTR [rdi], rdx
  test    rax, rax              // (3)
  je      .L3
  mov     rdi, rax
  jmp     operator delete[](void*) 
.L3:
  ret
```

What I am curious about is why GCC generates such inefficient code. The instruction (1) sets `[rdi]` to zero. That zero is then loaded into `rax` (2). And then, `rax` is tested (3) whether or not `operator delete` should be called.

Why GCC tests `rax` if it is guaranteed to be zero? It seems to be a pretty simple case for the optimizer to avoid this test.

Godbolt demo: https://godbolt.org/z/WNm2if

---

Another source of inefficiency is that 0 is written to `[rsi]` first (A) and then it is overwritten with another value (B).

Bottom line: I would expect a compiler to generate the same machine code for `std::swap` as well as for custom `swap`, which does not happen. This indicates that writing custom swapping functions makes sense even for classes that support move semantics.

Comment: At first glance, if rsi == rdi it's not guaranteed to be zero. But I can't explain what it's trying to do.

Comment: @Rup `rsi` and `rdi` point to swapped objects. Generally, they are different of course. But it's not relevant to my question.

Comment: Sorry, yes. I meant I can't explain why it would be testing equality at all, or testing it like that or calling delete if they are equal. It's relevant to your question "Why GCC tests rax if it is guaranteed to be zero" because rax is not guaranteed to be zero when rdi == rsi. Yes rdi and rsi ought to be different, but short of some guarantee they point to different objects how is the compiler to say that?

Comment: Perhaps the compiler does it whatever was the original size of the type. If it was eax instead of rax then it would be a good thing to set it to 0 because you would not replace the 32 bits on the left. That's just my guess though and I also add very poor code generated with Godbolt gcc compiler for c++ like:

        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rsi
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]

Comment: Changing the copy-assignment to `String& operator=(String&& other)` fixes it.Your version creates an extra object for each such call, and `std::swap` works by a series of 3 `operator=` calls if no specialized version exists

Comment: [Scott Meyers wrote](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2014/06/the-drawbacks-of-implementing-move.html) about the drawbacks of copy and swap in the world of move semantics. That's one of the drawbacks.

Comment: Even in OP's original code I don't see why the compiler fails to optimize out `test    rax, rax` (since it just loaded `rax` with `0`). Could be an optimization bug

Comment: By the way, the standard library tries ADL swap before `std::swap`, so if your code provides `swap` member function then standard library ops won't run into the problem (and nor will well-written user code that does ADL swap)

Comment: @M.M In the asm code, if `rsi` and `rdi` point to two 8byte memory with overlap but not identical, the `test` can't be optimized away.

Comment: @liliscent This case didn't come to my mind. But it's likely the reason and I would accept it as an answer. This also explains why in [this benchmark](http://quick-bench.com/gQNlsAsBUx9Orlnkuqw_ogqapnE) both `std::swap` and custom `swap` yield the same performance, since a compiler is likely able to recognize that both swapped pointers do not overlap / are different.

Comment: If the two data members partially overlap that way then at least one of them is misaligned which the compiler is normally allowed to assumed is impossible

Comment: @harold Yes, that's why I put that as a comment. I'm not sure whether this should be considered as a optimization bug. But the situation does seem to be a little complex for the compiler to figure out.

Comment: Add `__restrict` to the 2 arguments, and notice the difference.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Great, it works: https://godbolt.org/z/W_t4ZK. I didn't know GCC supported `__restrict` for references. Moreover, it works for Clang as well.

Comment: There is no issue of partial overlap, the compiler has trouble untangling the case where lhs and rhs are the same. To see that rax contains 0: it is read from rdi, which if rdi!=rsi had 0 last written to it, but otherwise had rax which itself had [rdi] which itself had 0 because rdi==rsi. Not trivial. (btw, the file created by -fdump-tree-optimized is more readable than asm)

Comment: I [reported this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80617) once.  It used to have more branches!

Comment: @DavisHerring that sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 2):

> The instruction (1) sets [rdi] to zero. That zero is then loaded into rax (2).

This isn't always the case, because rax is copied to [rsi] first, and there is no guarantee that [rsi] and [rdi] are different. So gcc cannot make this assumption, and it doesn't. Neither does any other compiler.

Edit (extracted from the comments): If [rsi] and [rdi] are the same, then [rdi] contains zero anyway (a "different" one that comes from Instruction A) and if they partially overlap, that's undefined behaviour and the compiler can assume it will never happen. But the optimiser doesn't see this far.

> This indicates that writing custom swapping functions makes sense even for classes that support move semantics.

Write *separate* copy assignment and move assignment operators, and the problem goes away. This newfangled pass-by-copy assignment operator looks like a brilliant idea, but as we can see, compilers may have some trouble optimising it away---and other compilers have *a lot* of trouble. Just look at the assembly generated by MSVC or clang.

Answer (score -1):

The reasoning is most likely that while the first code sample generates efficient code because there are no abstractions between the program and the desired executable (you are programming the swap).

In the second case, swap is a member of the standard library. which might have this check as a safety measure, which GCC simply did not optimize out.

Basically, I believe the standard library must have such safety checks. Writing code for a specific task will yield code optimized to the specific task. You do not need to cover all the possible cases that it might make sense to use swap.

Comment: In the source code of the primary template of `std::swap` provided by libstdc++, there are no safety checks: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/move.h#L196. The code is minimal.

Comment: While you are correct about the optimizer, I was making two separate points. 1. The standard library, by its nature, is not optimized to a specific use case, and 2. The optimizer is not able to optimize them out. These are two separate points, sorry if I didn’t make that clear.

Comment: As the comments above suggest your answer may not be quite correct think about correcting it, also this question is 4 years old and probably didn't need a new answer. Consider the layout and wording when you compose a response as yours doesn't parse too well.